# How to use text-transform:uppercase without move the rest of the sentence with :hover

Tags: html, css, hover, uppercase

I want to know how, only with html and css, i can transform some words (that are links) to uppercase without move all the sentence behind. Here are the example of how this like, in the footer section: https://codepen.io/JuanPastenCastillo/pen/RwGrPRa

And, here is the html and css:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 680px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.8rem auto 0 auto;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  line-height: 0.9rem;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
}

footer p {
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0.2rem 0 0 0;
}

footer p a {
  color: rgb(26, 26, 156);
  font-weight: 900;
}

footer p a:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer p a:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Created by JuanPasténCastilo.

  </p>
  <p>Social media <a href="https://twitter.com/JuanPastn2" target="_blank">Twitter</a> or <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/juan-past%C3%A9n-castillo-078b5817a/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>. My work on <a href="https://github.com/JuanPastenCastillo"
      target="_blank">Github</a></p>
</footer>
```

There is a way to do it but the result is a disordered sentence. The code is the following:

```css
footer a{
     display:inline-block;
     width:100px;
     text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks for you time and attention.

**(1° edit)**

I share some capture to explain how its like the disorder sentence: every time the mouse is hover the link this get in uppercase (this is what i want), but at the same time the rest of the left part of the sentence move a little to the left to give space to the word in the link (because the uppercase letter are bigger).

Here is a capture of the code when the mouse is hover, move the rest of the left sentence part
[image: Here is a capture of the code when the mouse is hover, move the rest of the left sentence part]

Here is a capture with the sentence fixed with the code, but doing that the sentence stay disorder
[image: Here is a capture with the sentence fixed with the code, but doing that the sentence stay disorder]

Comment: What are you asking specifically? What do you mean wIth 'disordered sentence'?

Comment: I can see you tried to add `font-family: monospace` but it's overwritten by `* {font-family: 'Rubik'}`. If you move the `font-family` from `*` to `body`, it will work fine.

Comment: I explain my self: with those style (the possible solution) the sentence have a empy space between the word with the link and the rest of the words (wich are in tag p). There is some way to remove that empy space? Or with that style solution is something necessary to make that flickers don't appear? @somethinghere

Comment: Thanks @ZsoltMeszaros  , i didn't realise of that detail.

Comment: Isnt that empty space a literal space character? Because theres no way to remove a textual space character apart from maybe collapsing them all...

Comment: @somethinghere ey! I added some captures to explain visually what i see and which is the problem i want to solve

Comment: Okauy so this is harder - you are trying to fight the fact that certain letters in fonts take up different sized spacing. It's never going to be perfect unless you tweak something like letter-spacing, and even then it's slightly dependent on the rendering engine used. Although in your snippet, it works fine because of the font chosen. Your snippet doesn't really have this issue.